# Scope of static methods in Java

Tags: java, eclipse

What is the scope of a static method in Java?

```
1) (Eclipse) Project level
2) Application level
3) JVM level
```

To give you insight into what I'm asking, if we have a class:

```
public class MyClass
{
   private static int data;
   public static void setData(int val)
   {
       data = val;
   }
   public static int getData()
   {
       return data;
   }
}
```

And if I make a call to the `setData()` method from a different class (in the same project as `MyClass`) and pass a value, say 10, will I be able to access the set `data` (i.e. value 10) from a different project? from a different application? etc-

Alternatively, what exactly would I need to do to be able to access the same `data` (i.e. 10) from a different (eclipse) project?

If there is official documentation regarding this, please do let me know.

Comment: This shouldn't compile. Since `setData` is `static`, it is not associated to any particular instance of `MyClass`.  But `data` is an instance variable, so `setData` won't see it.

Comment: Do you mean access the "setData" method, or access the static data that is set in the class?

Comment: None of the scopes you've listed are actual scopes. Java has no concept of a project, so there's no such thing as "project level" scope. The closest thing to "application level" or "JVM level" scope is public scope. I'm not sure what you mean by "user level" scope, but the user's ability to cause methods to run is determined by the program's logic, not by `public` or `static` modifiers.

Comment: @EricJablow Thanks for pointing out. I've corrected the code.

Comment: @HotLicks I meant the data (integer variable)

Comment: See the middle paragraph of my answer.  The static data is accessible only within the JVM and "lives", at most, for the life of the JVM.

Comment: @HotLicks - You are right. Deleted my comments.

Comment: Re documentation, get a copy of the JVM reference manual, and read up on the class loading sequence.  It specifies when static variables are allocated.

Comment: @user2246674 I've made a couple edits. Please do let me know if you still find it vague.

Comment: Note that in order to share data between JVMs (whether they exist at the same time or at different times) one must use some operating system facility such as files, "sockets", or shared memory.  Sharing between JVMs is not a part of the Java language/specification.

Comment: @RockyInde The very terms used (incorrectly?) make it vague. I hope that the comments and answers (including the proper terminology) clear up the subject :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's assume you are talking about whether there is one "instance" of `data` and the corresponding static method.

> What is the scope of a static method in Java?
>
> 1) (Eclipse) Project level

No.  Source code / build time "project" structure has direct relevance to the runtime behaviour of a Java program.  (The project build produces one or more .class files, typically bundled up as JAR or WAR or EAR or whatever archive files.  The runtime behaviour depends on how those files are loaded into a JVM.)

> 2) Application level
>   3) JVM level

Yes, no, maybe.

The actual "existence scope" (as someone described it) depends on the identity of the class type.  Under normal circumstances, a class is loaded into a JVM once.  That gives you one class type, and there is one instance of the static variables for that type.

However, if your classloaders are organized in the right way, you can then load the class again.  This gives you a new class type (with the same name as the previous one ... but a different classloader), and that class type has its own set of static variable.

An application that is run using the `java` command via its `main` method will typically only load the class once.  (You'd typically need to create a new classloader at runtime to change this.)

However, applications (e.g. webapps) that are run within frameworks are subject to whatever the framework does.  And a typical appserver framework uses a separate classloader for each webapp.  So if you include a JAR file in multiple webapps and run them in the same appserver, you are likely to get multiple class types with the same name and different classloaders .... and different static variable sets.

But it doesn't end there, because when you call `MyClass.getData()` in another class (e.g. `OtherClass`), the variable that is accessed depends on which `MyClass` type the `OtherClass` code has been bound to.  And that depends on what the `OtherClass` type's classloader bound it to ... when it loaded the `OtherClass` class.

This can all get rather complicated, but normally you don't need to worry about it.  The complexity only happens when something is doing "clever classloader stuff", and even, then the clever stuff is usually implementing separation of "apps" that you *want* to happen.

Answer (score 2):

Are you asking about the reference scope or the existence scope?  A public static method can be accessed by any class which can access the method's class, given standard Java package naming/scoping rules.  Note that this implies (as part of the rules) that access is only available to classes in the same JVM.

The *existence* of the *data* is scoped to the instance of `java.lang.Class` that represents the class being loaded (I'm sure there's some fancy term for this).  At most this is until the end of execution of the JVM, but a class can, under some circumstances, be "unloaded" earlier.

It should also be noted that more than one copy (`java.lang.Class` instance) of a given class can be loaded in a given JVM at the same time, and each copy of the class would have its own static variables.  However, this would be pretty rare.

Comment: I am asking about the existence scope. Also, the `data` that I'm talking about is `static`. Would it still be associated with an instance of the class? Also, would it make a difference if I made my class itself to be `static`?

Comment: @RockyInde - Yes, in Java static data is associated with an "instance".  But note that it's an instance of `Class`, not an instance of the class being discussed.  When a class is loaded an instance of `Class` is created to represent the class, and any static data is (at least conceptually) associated with that.

Comment: And note that you can't make an "outer" class "static".

Answer (score 0):

`static` methods do not have a special scope. Scope is defined by the use of access specifier. As you have defined the static method as `public` so it will be visible to all the classes in the same or different package.

If you want to use it in different project, then either you import the source of your current project in the new project or you create the jar of your current project and add it to the classpath of your new project.

Comment: @JunedAhsan I tried out what you described in the second paragraph, but I wasn't able to access the data.

Comment: @RockyInde You need to access a static member in a static way i.e using the className.staticMethod. For your case it should be used like this MyClass.getData(), provided you have imported the class properly.

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly what you asked, but I believe it might help you understand the concept of  `static` methods.

Let say, you have class `Foo` with **static** method `calculateFoo1()` and **non-static** method  `calculateFoo2()`

Non-static methods can be used only in association with `object` of this class (class `instance`). So before you can call it you need to instantiate the object.

```
Foo f2 = new Foo();
cf.calculateFoo2;
```

Static method can be called using Class name without instance of this class.

```
Foo.calculateFoo1();
```

You are allowed to call static method using instance of this class as well (if you have it).  Compiler will understand.

Answer (score 0):

You mixed two concepts son.
static means you have one instance per class.

Scope is depending on the access modifiers (private, public, protected, default)

If you want to access this method from other eclipse project, you need to add this project to the the project library.

Right click on your new project, select Build Path, then Add to Build Path
Go to projects tab, and add your project that has this getDate method.

Now you can access your class MyClass