# Having troubles returning an updated value in a different class

Tags: java, class, return-value

So what I'm trying to do is get my Test1 class to print out the updated value of newText when method menuSelection is used. So lets say: menuOption = 1; I want to update my newText variable to be 0 so when I print it out in my Test1 class it prints out 0. The issue is even after I use the menuSelection method it's not updating my newText variable as it only prints out 1.

---

import java.util.Scanner;

```
  public class Test {

      public static int newText = 1;

      public static int menuSelection(){
         Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

         int menuOption = scan.nextInt();

         while((menuOption < 0)||(menuOption > 2)) {
            System.out.print("Not a valid option, please press 1 or 2 ");
            menuOption = scan.nextInt();
        }


        if(menuOption == 1 ){
           newText = 0;
        }
        if(menuOption == 2){
           newText = 1;

        }
        return newText;
     }
 }
```

---

```
public class Test1 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
      int newText = Test.newText;
      System.out.print(newText);
      Test.menuSelection();
      System.out.println(newText);
   }
}
```

Comment: Place a breakpoint before the if clause to view what value is actually being passed into the method.

Answer (score 1):

you wrote your method like this

```
 public static int menuSelection(){
```

but you didn't get return value in main method.

so you can fix your code just this line.

AS-IS

```
Test.menuSelection();
```

TO-BE

```
newText = Test.menuSelection();
```

but If you want to the static value `newText` then you change your variable name.
I think you feel confusing about `scope`.

[reference link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18927856/scope-of-static-methods-in-java)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you didn't assign the value from the method call. A more fundamental issue is that you are using static values to pass information between classes.

You should not be using `static fields` to pass values. Nor, in most cases should you be using static methods (but there are exceptions).  Just do it as follows with instance or local fields as appropriate.

```
public class MenuTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
       // instantiate an instance of the class.
        Test mt = new Test();
        int newText = 1;
        System.out.print(newText);
        // invoke the method and get the return value.
        newText = mt.menuSelection();

        System.out.println(newText);
    }
}

class Test {

    public int menuSelection() {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        int returnValue = 0;
        int menuOption = scan.nextInt();

        while ((menuOption < 0) || (menuOption > 2)) {
            System.out.print(
                    "Not a valid option, please press 1 or 2 ");
            menuOption = scan.nextInt();
        }

        if (menuOption == 1) {
            returnValue = 0;
        }
        if (menuOption == 2) {
            returnValue = 1;

        }
        return returnValue;
    }
}
```

I renamed the `newText` field to `returnValue` to emphasize that it is an entirely different variable than local one you use in main.